# Passing selected row IDs from jqGrid to ASP.Net MVC Controller Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have cascading jqGrids (State, then City, then Zipcode) on a View with multirow on. I can select one or more of the ID values for the zip code by grabbing data using the following:

```
var s;
s = jQuery("#zipList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

"s" ends up containing something that looks like "23,119,5932,44". I am trying to pass that string (or a collection containing those items) to a Controller action that looks something like (so I can do something to each selected zip):

```
public ActionResult ProcessZips(string selectedZips)
{
    // do something
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult ProcessZips(List<string> selectedZips)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: What is your question, precisely?

Comment: I would like a more elegant method of using Html.BeginForm() in my ASP.Net MVC view to pass form values to an ActionResult in my controller. I can easily do this with the form elements I define either using <input> tags, the Html helpers, or dynamically with the FormCollection, but I don't know how to get the selected values from the jqGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's goofy, but I'm have it working by using OnSelectRow and OnSelectAll to update a hidden field in my form with the selected ID values. I can easily grab that in the form submission using the BeginForm helper.

Comment: I'd probably use `form.onSubmit` instead.